# Counting how many times each word occurs in a file using map. (c++)

Tags: c++, string, file-io, dictionary

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("myTextFile.txt");
    if ( fin.fail()){
        cout << "Could not open input file.";
        exit(1);
    }

    string next;
    map <string, int> words;
    while (fin >> next){
        words[next]++;
    }
    cout << "\n\n" << "Number of words: " << words[next] << endl;

    fin.close();
    fin.open("myTextFile.txt");
    while (fin >> next){
        cout << next << ": " << words[next] << endl;
    }

    fin.close();
    return 0;
}
```

My main problem is that when a word occurs more than once, it is also listed more then once. i.e if the text starts with "hello hello" then cout produces:
"hello: 2" '\n' "hello: 2"

Also, i'd like not to have to close, and then reopen the file for the second while to be true. It seems like its still at the end of the file from the last while loop.

Comment: Your number of words will only print the last word's count. Also, iterate through the map, don't read the file a second time (assuming you changed the name and forgot to change the other one, judging by how you say reopen).

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate trough the map, and not open the file a second time.

Look at the code sample provided [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/begin/).

EDIT: here a code sample that iterates trough a map

```
// map::begin/end
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main ()
{
  std::map<char,int> mymap;
  std::map<char,int>::iterator it;

  mymap['b'] = 100;
  mymap['a'] = 200;
  mymap['c'] = 300;

  // show content:
  for (std::map<char,int>::iterator it=mymap.begin(); it!=mymap.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
a => 200
b => 100
c => 300
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need re-open file:

```
for (auto i = words.begin(); i != words.end(); i++)
{
  cout << i->first << " : " << i->second << endl;
}
```

or simpler:

```
for (const auto &i : words)
{
  cout << i.first << " : " << i.second << endl;
}
```

Comment: If you're using C++11, might as well use ranged-based for too!

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the map after you set it and then you do not need to open the file again, this is trivial example:

```
int main()
{
  std::map<std::string, int> m1 ;

  m1["hello"] = 2 ;
  m1["world"] = 4 ;

  for( const auto &entry : m1 )
  {
    std::cout << entry.first << " : " << entry.second << std::endl ;
  }
}
```

The expected output would be:

```
hello : 2
world : 4
```